# C# Reflection "strange" benchmarks when concatenating property values to a string

Tags: c#, reflection, benchmarking

I tried to make some reflection benchmark tests, but mostly I managed to confuse myself. Can please someone explain why both tests pass?

For the first one I was expecting it to fail, but the times I got were:

**millisecondsReflection - 4970 ms**

**milliseconds - 6935 ms**

```
    [Fact]
    public void PropertiesGetterString()
    {
        var bar = new Bar
        {
            Id = 42,
            Number = "42",
        };

        string concat = string.Empty;
        string concatReflection = string.Empty;

        var props = bar.GetType().GetProperties();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            concatReflection += props[1].GetValue(bar);
        }

        sw.Stop();

        long millisecondsReflection = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        sw.Reset();

        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            concat += bar.Number;
        }

        sw.Stop();

        long milliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        millisecondsReflection.Should().BeLessOrEqualTo(milliseconds);
    }
```

I figured it is something to do with the string concatenation or type conversion, so I changed it to a list append, and got the expected results, i.e. the reflection was slower.

```
    [Fact]
    public void PropertiesGetterArray()
    {
        var bar = new Bar
        {
            Id = 42,
            Number = "42",
        };

        List<object> concat = new List<object>();
        List<object> concatReflection = new List<object>();

        var props = bar.GetType().GetProperties();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            concatReflection.Add(props[1].GetValue(bar));
        }

        sw.Stop();

        long millisecondsReflection = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            concat.Add(bar.Number);
        }

        sw.Stop();

        long milliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        millisecondsReflection.Should().BeGreaterOrEqualTo(milliseconds);
    }
```

Here the results were:

**millisecondsReflection - 184 ms**

**milliseconds - 11 ms**

My question is what I am missing out here?

**P.S. Times taken are while in Debug Mode. As shown in the comments in Release Mode the times are very close to each other**

Comment: What result you get with StringBuilder

Comment: You're generating a lot of pressure on the GC, what if the GC kicks in in the middle of the second loop, due to all the pressure the first loop put on it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen switching the loop places does not change the results

Comment: @Prix with StringBuilder reflection - 16ms, direct property access - 1 ms

Comment: So it's almost all overhead due to string concatenation.

Comment: This test basically proves why using StringBuilder is a better idea.

Comment: Yes, noticed that now, removed my comment.

Comment: I could reproduce your first test by compiling in debug mode, then the difference disappears when compiling in release mode. So it seems there is some optimization that is kicking in the reflection case but not the other. The lesson to learn is that benchmark are irrelevant if not done in release mode. That said, I'm curious to know what optimization is kicking-in in debug mode, and why it occurs only in one of the two loops

Comment: When I test this I get almost identical results from the two loops, they run around 5 seconds in all cases, both +/- by about a 100ms, most likely due to other things happening on my computer. Compiling for release reduces to around 4600ms +/- 100, and both vary with +/- 100 so sometimes the first loop is slightly faster, sometimes it is slightly longer. I changed the test though to separate out the code to test into separate methods and doing a full GC between each step.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen What happens if you increase the loop bounds? I presume the difference will be more noticeable.

Comment: I will switch from LINQPad to a proper project and run it using a profiler.

Comment: When I ran this using a profiler then string concatenation took 2426 ms in the reflection loop, 2416 in the direct property loop, and PropertyInfo.GetValue took 50ms total. Basically, this is variation due to computer doing other stuff. Let me try the code in the question because I think there's too many oddities with that code.

Comment: Well, I basically cannot reproduce this disparity. When I added code to simply output the timings to the console, but kept the code exactly as shown in the question, the first example code took 2523 and 2487 ms respectively, as expected it is only slightly faster as most of the time is spent creating new strings, the ~50ms is the PropertyInfo.GetValue property. Can you reproduce this disparity *every time*?

Comment: More timings: 2530/2507, 2519/2501, 2506/2502, 2528/2563. This just tells me two things: reflection is not as bad as I thought, as long as I have cached the PropertyInfo, and that the usage of StringBuilder is **entirely warranted!**

Comment: @KooKiz is on to something. The times that I got are taken while in debug mode. Still curious what optimizations are being made. Any chance for branch prediction at this point?

Comment: Branch prediction is a cpu feature not a compiler or jitter feature, this happens in both DEBUG and RELEASE.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you are absolutely right also for the use of StringBuilder. I still can't find correlation why in DEBUG the times differ so much in favour of reflection

Comment: DEBUG does *a lot* with the code to keep variables around more than necessary, inject more checks, stop inlining of methods, etc. You **should never performance profile DEBUG code**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SUMMARY**

This discrepancy is being caused two things: The overhead of string concatenation, which is swamping the overhead of the reflection; and a difference in the way that debug builds handle the lifetime of locals.

The difference in times you're seeing between release and debug builds is due to the way that a debug build keeps any locals alive until the end of a method, in contrast to a release build.

This is causing the GC of the two strings in the code to behave very differently between release and debug builds.

**DETAILED ANALYSIS**

If you change the test code to just sum the lengths of the string properties instead, you get the expected result.

Here's my results (release build):

```
Trial 1
Length = 20000000
Length = 20000000
Without reflection: 8
With reflection: 1613
Trial 2
Length = 20000000
Length = 20000000
Without reflection: 8
With reflection: 1606
Trial 3
Length = 20000000
Length = 20000000
Without reflection: 8
With reflection: 1598
Trial 4
Length = 20000000
Length = 20000000
Without reflection: 8
With reflection: 1609
Trial 5
Length = 20000000
Length = 20000000
Without reflection: 9
With reflection: 1619
```

And the test code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    class Bar
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (int trial = 1; trial <= 5; ++trial)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trial " + trial);
                PropertiesGetterString();
            }
        }

        public static void PropertiesGetterString()
        {
            int count = 10000000;

            var bar = new Bar
            {
                Id = 42,
                Number = "42",
            };

            int totalLength = 0;

            var props = bar.GetType().GetProperties();

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                totalLength += ((string)props[1].GetValue(bar)).Length;
            }

            sw.Stop();
            long millisecondsReflection = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("Length = " + totalLength);

            sw.Reset();
            totalLength = 0;
            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                totalLength += bar.Number.Length;
            }

            sw.Stop();
            long milliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("Length = " + totalLength);

            Console.WriteLine("Without reflection: " + milliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("With reflection: " + millisecondsReflection);
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that I can only reproduce your original results with a debug build rather than a release build.

If I change my test code to do string concatenation as per your OP, I get these results:

```
Trial 1
Without reflection: 3686
With reflection: 3661
Trial 2
Without reflection: 3584
With reflection: 3688
Trial 3
Without reflection: 3587
With reflection: 3676
Trial 4
Without reflection: 3550
With reflection: 3700
Trial 5
Without reflection: 3564
With reflection: 3659
```

Finally, as a further attempt to minimise the effects of background GC on the two loops, I added the following code after each call to `sw.Stop()`:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Which changed the results to:

```
Trial 1
Without reflection: 3565
With reflection: 3665
Trial 2
Without reflection: 3538
With reflection: 3631
Trial 3
Without reflection: 3535
With reflection: 3597
Trial 4
Without reflection: 3558
With reflection: 3629
Trial 5
Without reflection: 3551
With reflection: 3599
```

With that change, all the "with reflection" results are slower than the "without reflection" results, as you'd expect.

Finally, let's investigate the difference observed in debug mode.

It would appear that the difference is occurring because of the order of the loops. If you try one test with the reflection loop before the direct loop, you get different results from vice-versa.

Here's the results of my final test program:

```
Trial 1
PropertiesGetterStringWithoutThenWithReflection()
Without reflection: 3228
With reflection: 5866
PropertiesGetterStringWithThenWithoutReflection()
Without reflection: 5780
With reflection: 3273
Trial 2
PropertiesGetterStringWithoutThenWithReflection()
Without reflection: 3207
With reflection: 5921
PropertiesGetterStringWithThenWithoutReflection()
Without reflection: 5802
With reflection: 3318
Trial 3
PropertiesGetterStringWithoutThenWithReflection()
Without reflection: 3246
With reflection: 5873
PropertiesGetterStringWithThenWithoutReflection()
Without reflection: 5882
With reflection: 3297
Trial 4
PropertiesGetterStringWithoutThenWithReflection()
Without reflection: 3261
With reflection: 5891
PropertiesGetterStringWithThenWithoutReflection()
Without reflection: 5778
With reflection: 3298
Trial 5
PropertiesGetterStringWithoutThenWithReflection()
Without reflection: 3267
With reflection: 5948
PropertiesGetterStringWithThenWithoutReflection()
Without reflection: 5830
With reflection: 3306
```

Note that whichever loop is run first is fastest, regardless of whether it is doing reflection. This implies that the difference is some artifact of the way that the string handling is being done in the debug build.

I suspect what might be happening is that the debug build keeps the concatenated string alive for the entire method, whereas for the release build does not, which will affect the GC.

Here's the test code for the above results:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    class Bar
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (int trial = 1; trial <= 5; ++trial)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trial " + trial);
                PropertiesGetterStringWithoutThenWithReflection();
                PropertiesGetterStringWithThenWithoutReflection();
            }
        }

        public static void PropertiesGetterStringWithoutThenWithReflection()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PropertiesGetterStringWithoutThenWithReflection()");

            int count = 100000;

            var bar = new Bar
            {
                Id = 42,
                Number = "42",
            };

            var props = bar.GetType().GetProperties();
            string concat1 = "";
            string concat2 = "";

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                concat2 += bar.Number;
            }

            sw.Stop();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            long milliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            sw.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                concat1 += (string)props[1].GetValue(bar);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            long millisecondsReflection = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            Console.WriteLine("Without reflection: " + milliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("With reflection: " + millisecondsReflection);
        }

        public static void PropertiesGetterStringWithThenWithoutReflection()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PropertiesGetterStringWithThenWithoutReflection()");

            int count = 100000;

            var bar = new Bar
            {
                Id = 42,
                Number = "42",
            };

            var props = bar.GetType().GetProperties();
            string concat1 = "";
            string concat2 = "";

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                concat1 += (string)props[1].GetValue(bar);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            long millisecondsReflection = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            sw.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                concat2 += bar.Number;
            }

            sw.Stop();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            long milliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            Console.WriteLine("Without reflection: " + milliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("With reflection: " + millisecondsReflection);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I've reproduced the difference in a release build too. I think this proves that as I suspected, the difference is due to how long the strings are kept alive for.

Here's the test code, to be run as a RELEASE build:

```
public static void PropertiesGetterString()
{
    int count = 100000;

    var bar = new Bar
    {
        Id = 42,
        Number = "42",
    };

    var props = bar.GetType().GetProperties();
    string concat1 = "";
    string concat2 = "";

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        concat1 += (string)props[1].GetValue(bar);
    }

    sw.Stop();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    long millisecondsReflection = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    sw.Restart();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        concat2 += bar.Number;
    }

    sw.Stop();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    long milliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine("Without reflection: " + milliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("With reflection: " + millisecondsReflection);
    Console.WriteLine(concat1.Length + concat2.Length); // Try with and without this line commented out.
}
```

If I run that as-is, I get the following results:

```
Trial 1
Without reflection: 4957
With reflection: 3646
400000
Trial 2
Without reflection: 4941
With reflection: 3626
400000
Trial 3
Without reflection: 4969
With reflection: 3609
400000
Trial 4
Without reflection: 5021
With reflection: 3690
400000
Trial 5
Without reflection: 4769
With reflection: 3637
400000
```

Note how the first loop (with reflection) is faster than the second (without reflection).

Now comment out the last line of the method (the line that is outputting the length of the two strings) and run it again. This time the results are:

```
Trial 1
Without reflection: 3558
With reflection: 3690
Trial 2
Without reflection: 3653
With reflection: 3624
Trial 3
Without reflection: 3606
With reflection: 3663
Trial 4
Without reflection: 3592
With reflection: 3660
Trial 5
Without reflection: 3629
With reflection: 3644
```

This, I think, proves that the difference between the debug and the release build times is due to the fact that a debug build keeps alive all locals until the end of a method (so that they can be displayed in the debugger even if you've stepped past the last use of them in the method).

By contrast, a release build can GC a reference any time after its last use in a method.

Comment: `Also note that I couldn't reproduce your original results` I managed to by running the code in debug mode

Comment: But you should never compare performance in debug mode. Contrived examples will give you contrived results. Please don't do that!

Comment: While this proves that in Release the times are close, I still can't see why in Debug the times differ so much in favour of reflection..

Comment: @gyosifov They don't differ in favour of reflection - they differ in favour of whichever is the first loop (and for debug builds only). See my final edit.

Comment: @gyosifov And finally, see my last edit. I think I've proved that it's the debugger keeping the strings alive (thus ineligible for GC) that's making the difference.